# How can I access the weather description in the json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have below json object, I want to display the weather object description, when I try to display the object its giving undefined. can any one tell me how do I access it?

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 80.28,
    "lat": 13.09
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 299.15,
    "pressure": 1015,
    "humidity": 74,
    "temp_min": 299.15,
    "temp_max": 299.15
  },
  "visibility": 6000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.1,
    "deg": 60
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1519491600,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 7834,
    "message": 0.0057,
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1519433836,
    "sunset": 1519476414
  },
  "id": 1264527,
  "name": "Chennai",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the attr description?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Assumption:  var data = { ..<your JSON Data >... }
Use property method:  data.weather[0].id, etc.
Use associative array index:  data["weather"][0]["id"], etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `weather` is an array, so you need to iterate through the objects.

You can use the function `forEach`.

```js
var obj = {  "coord": {    "lon": 80.28,    "lat": 13.09  },  "weather": [{    "id": 800,    "main": "Clear",    "description": "clear sky",    "icon": "01n"  }],  "base": "stations",  "main": {    "temp": 299.15,    "pressure": 1015,    "humidity": 74,    "temp_min": 299.15,    "temp_max": 299.15  },  "visibility": 6000,  "wind": {    "speed": 3.1,    "deg": 60  },  "clouds": {    "all": 0  },  "dt": 1519491600,  "sys": {    "type": 1,    "id": 7834,    "message": 0.0057,    "country": "IN",    "sunrise": 1519433836,    "sunset": 1519476414  },  "id": 1264527,  "name": "Chennai",  "cod": 200};

obj.weather.forEach(w => console.log(w.description));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

Just access the `weather` property of the object, which is an array of just one item (item [0]), which is another object and then the `description` property of that object:

```js
var obj = {"coord":{"lon":80.28,"lat":13.09},
"weather":[
        {"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}
    ],
"base":"stations",
"main":{"temp":299.15,"pressure":1015,"humidity":74,"temp_min":299.15,"temp_max":299.15},
"visibility":6000,
"wind":{"speed":3.1,"deg":60},
"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1519491600,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":7834,"message":0.0057,"country":"IN","sunrise":1519433836,"sunset":1519476414},
"id":1264527,"name":"Chennai","cod":200
};

console.log(obj.weather[0].description);
```

If you have any control over the JSON that is coming back, it doesn't seem like `weather` needs to have an array that contains an object. If there will always be just one object, it would make more sense for the structure to be:

```
{"coord":{"lon":80.28,"lat":13.09},
"weather":{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"},
...
```